# How to retrieve specific user from realtime Firebase in Android Studio

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

Hello I am currently doing an appointment chatting application between counsellors and user.

The image is the screenshot of realtime Firebase.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQG8x.png

So i am trying to do chatting function after the counsellors accepted the booking appointment from the users. However , in my case , it retrieve every counsellors information including counsellors that does not accept the booking. [Screenshot of every counsellor appears in my list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTxfz.jpg). I would like to only show "mary" because she is only who accept the appointment booking however according to the image , it shows mary and farah. I would be kindly appreciate if anyone could help me. Thank you.

The following is the code that display every counsellors.

```
private void displayData(){
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Counsellors");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //mUsers.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Counsellors counsellor = snapshot.getValue(Counsellors.class);
                if (counsellor!=null && counsellor.getId()!= null && !counsellor.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                    mUsers.add(counsellor);
                }

                userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(),mUsers);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

JSON snippets of my realtime Firebase ( Appointment, Counsellors , Users and Chat )

```html
{
  "Appointment" : {
    "-Mo69loW59iUHIMNfLOf" : {
      "date" : "11/26/21",
      "idDoctor" : "M8EUBl4vRubeW8iS92HiVIuY4rJ2",
      "idPatient" : "4WJh1MmoEfN4sqNaJrqbHhNFjxr1",
      "status" : "Accepted",
      "time" : "16:06"
    }
  },
  "Chat" : {
    "-Mo6A8oY1Kt_ni71IlGN" : {
      "message" : "helo ",
      "receiver" : "4WJh1MmoEfN4sqNaJrqbHhNFjxr1",
      "sender" : "M8EUBl4vRubeW8iS92HiVIuY4rJ2"
    }
  },
  "Counsellors" : {
    "M8EUBl4vRubeW8iS92HiVIuY4rJ2" : {
      "email" : "mary@gmail.com",
      "id" : "M8EUBl4vRubeW8iS92HiVIuY4rJ2",
      "name" : "mary",
      "specialist" : "family mental health"
    },
    "v5FgbL4GuLeOE9ySVe7tgVFEk5D2" : {
      "email" : "farah24@gmail.com",
      "id" : "v5FgbL4GuLeOE9ySVe7tgVFEk5D2",
      "name" : "farah",
      "specialist" : "anxiety"
    }
  },
  "Users" : {
    "4WJh1MmoEfN4sqNaJrqbHhNFjxr1" : {
      "email" : "jett24@gmail.com",
      "id" : "4WJh1MmoEfN4sqNaJrqbHhNFjxr1",
      "matric" : "BI18110293",
      "name" : "jett"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a JSON snippet of a screenshot of your "Counsellors" node.

Comment: hello sir i just added the JSON snippet including appointment , chat , user and Counsellors node.

Comment: I would really appreciate if u could help me sir . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

first of all from my experience with Firebase, I will recommend you to migrate all your data from a real-time database to the Firestore database. Real-time to use only for chatting purposes.

Here is the documentation for the difference between these two databases:
[RTDB vs Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore)

The second thing is if you need help, please post code snippets to see if there is something wrong with the code. From the text, we cannot help you make fixes in your project.

Comment: Hello i am sorry that i did not post the code snippets. I just posted the code snippets. I would appreciate if you could help . Thank you

Comment: Thank you for showing up the code. The issue is exactly what I told you in the latest post. You are getting all the data that were changed but you want to get only one object not two. My solution is to migrate all data to the Firestore database instead of this real-time. It is easier to manipulate the data on the app development side or the front-end of the mobile app. That's my main suggestion. The second thing that you could do is that you select only the first element of fetched data but that's not quite of solution for this issue.